# Vertical Align CSS

Tags: css, center, vertical-alignment

I want these two text fields to be in the center of the page (horizontally and vertically)... What's wrong with my code?

```
<div style="vertical-align:middle; height:100%">
<center>
<form action="register.php" method="post">
Desired Username: <textarea type="text" name="user_username" style="width:60%;"></textarea><br>
Desired Password: <textarea type="text" name="user_password" style="width:60%;"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submitButton"/> <a href="http://www.********.com/register.php"><button name="Register">Register</button></a>
</form>
</center>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) show your CSS code & 2) <center>is now a deprecated character which is not reliable by modern browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting it inside a table worked! apparently that property works for tables not divs..

```
<div style="height:100%; text-align:center;"> 
<table height="100%" style="height:100%;"> 
<td height="100%" style="vertical-align:middle; height:100%;"> 
<center>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. `<center>` **is deprecated.** Use CSS to center horizontally instead. For example, you can add `text-align:center` on the container and `text-align:left` on the element in question, or `margin:0 auto` for fluid width elements.
2. `vertical-align:middle;` **only really makes sense for table cells or elements set to** `display:table-cell;`**.** If you were trying to center an image or one line of text, it would be as easy as setting the line height of the element equal to its height.

Since we're looking at something a bit more complicated here, you just need to experiment a little. I threw [this](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/rUjZ2/) together:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

form {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-1em;
}
```

I used `-1em` because if, for example, I had two lines of text, `1em` would be half the height of the block that those lines occupy. Since `input`s are about the same height as a normal uppercase character, give or take a few pixels, `1em` should give you about half the height of the block that those inputs occupy.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I center vertically as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can center by giving your main content div fixed dimensions and then using `margin: 25% auto;`  The auto will center it horizontally and the percentage should center it vertically.

Edit: Here is a better solution for vertically align that I have used in the past, you set a parent div with a height of 50% and negative margin bottom  that is half of the content height.

So for example :

```
#parent {float:left; height:50%; margin-bottom:-50px;}
#child {clear:both; height:100px; position:relative;}

<div id="parent">
<div id="child">
    Content 
</div>
</div>
```

From [this source](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/)

Comment: But won't that center it below the center if I said something like 50% and my two input areas took up 100 pixels total wouldn't that be 100 pixels below the center?

Comment: <div style="height:100%; text-align:center;">
<table height="100%" style="height:100%;">
<td height="100%" style="vertical-align:middle; height:100%;">
<center>

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw, Reading the comments, it looks like you did something completely different from Zac's answer.  Please do not accept an answer if it did not solve your problem.  **You are free to post your own solution as an answer, and accept that instead.**

Comment: @Zac, How exactly does simply setting a 25% top/bottom center it vertically?  If it were that easy, we wouldn't have ten thousand "how do I center vertically?" questions on SO.

Comment: @Sparky, yes you are right it is dependent on what the parent div is and I was in a hurry last night when I wrote that.. I will update my answer.

Comment: Sorry! I had no clue I could post my own solution haha! I was simply checking it so other could find the solution, I had forgotten that it awards users for having their answer checked... I'll go back and fix this! :) Thanks guys!